# create boxes with a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to convert this old javascript into jquery in order to learn jquery.

The goal of the old javascript was to add a box to the page when the button "add box" is clicked. when the box itself is clicked on, display a unique id.

I am stuck on how to correctly code the div, and add a box onto it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>E10W12</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        .clrBox { 
            background-color: orange;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script src="E10W12.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Box">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Old Javascript:

```
window.onload = init;

var i= 0;

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

function handleButtonClick(e) { 
    i++;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","clrBox");
    div.setAttribute("id","Box"+i);
    div.onclick=function(){handleBoxClick(div);}
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body[0].appendChild(div);
}

function handleBoxClick(el){
    alert(el.id);
}
```

New JQuery to replace Javascript:

```
var i = 0;

$(function() {
    $( '#addButton').click(function(){
        i++;

        Not sure what to do here?

    });
});
```

Alright, I got it using the two answers provided below. Thanks guys!

Solution:

```
$(function() {

var i = 0;

    $( '#addButton').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('<div/>', {
            'id': 'Box' + i,
            'class': 'clrBox'
        }).appendTo('body');


        $("div").click(function () {
             alert(this.id);
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('<div/>', {
    'id': 'Box' + i,
    'class': 'clrBox',
    click: function(){handleBoxClick($(this));}
}).appendTo('body');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65gG6/1/)

For [further reading.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Comment: works perfect. sadly whenever I click on a box it doesn't display the id. This is the format that I have it:

var i = 0;

$(function() {
    $( '#addButton').click(function(){
  i++;
  $('<div/>', {
   'id': 'Box' + i,
   'class': 'clrBox',
   click: function(){handleBoxClick(div);}
  }).appendTo('body');
    });
 
 function handleBoxClick(el){
  alert(el.id);
 }

});

Comment: a little better. however whenever i click the box it now the alert says "unidentified"

Comment: Per OP - "The goal of the old javascript was to add a box to the page when the button "add box" is clicked. when the box itself is clicked on, display a unique id"  This is not a full solution to the original question asked.

Comment: @user2961971 you are receiving a jquery object, It doesn't has a direct property called `id`. You have to use .attr('id') to retrieve that. Try out my demo.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
$(function(){
    var id = 0;
    $('#addButton').click(function(){
        id++;
        $('<div />', {
            'id' : 'box ' + id,
            'class': 'clrBox',
            click : function(){
                $(this).html($(this).attr('id'));
            }            
        }).appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXxAW/)**

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/XZK95/1/

```
            var i = 0
            $("#addButton").click(function () {
                i++
                $("#myForm").append("<div id=\"Box" + i + "\"></div>");
                $("div").click(function () {
                    $(this).html(this.id);
                })
            });
```